# Convert sql date to Joda Datetime

Tags: java, date

Trying to convert a yyyy-MM-dd format into MM-dd-yyyy using Joda.

Invalid format: "2013-02-20" is malformed at "13-02-20"

```
String date = "2013-02-20";
DateTimeFormatter dft = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.parse(date, dft);
```

Comment: In planet Earth and in Gregorian calendars we only have 12 months, there's no month 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input pattern does not match the input date `String`. It should be

```
String date = "2013-02-20";
DateTimeFormatter dft = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime d2 = DateTime.parse(date, dft);
System.out.println(d2.toString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

Comment: Id like to go from yyyy-MM-dd to MM-dd-yyyy, would that mean id still have to use SimpleDateFormat?

Comment: You mean change the output pattern. No need for that. `JodaTime` has everything you need. See update